# Get textarea value on click of button inside a Tab using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to text to appear within a textarea that is within a tab in the UI tabs widget. So I have a button asking how you are feeling. If nothing is chosen in the 2nd tab then it should display a message in the text area. Right now I click the button and no text appears even if I use the .html or .text or .val methods. Any idea?

```js
$(function() {
  $( ".draggable" ).draggable(); 
 $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
      if (ui.draggable.attr("id") == "gplan") {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
          .html( "Great Plan Picked!" );
      }
   
      if (ui.draggable.attr("id") == "pplan") {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
          .html( "Poor Plan Picked!" );
      } 
    }
  }); //end of droppable
});//end of $(function(){
 
$("#feelings").click(function(){
  var gPlan = $("#gplan").val();
  var pPlan = $("#pplan").val();
  if(!gPlan && !pPlan) {
    $("textarea").val("I don't know");
  }

window.onload = function (){
 $("#feelings").click(function(){
  
  var gPlan = $("#gplan").val()
  var pPlan = $("#pplan").val()
  
 
  if(!gPlan && !pPlan)
  
  {
   $("textarea").html("I don't know").effect("bounce", 1000);
  }
  

  if(pPlan)

  

{


 $(this).html("I feel great!");
  }

 

 if(gPlan)
  {


 $(this).html("My Head Hurts!");
  }

  
 }); // end of feelings click 

}); // end of feelings click
```

```html
  

 <div id="tabs-1">
        <h2>Sign Up</h2>
    <form id="myform">
    <br>
    <label for="first_name">First Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" required> <span class="error" id="first_error"></span>
    <br>

    <br>
    <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" required> <span class="error" id="last_error"></span>
    <br>

    <br>
    <label for="last_name">Start Date:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" required> <span class="error" id="date_error"></span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span class="error" id="all_error"></span>

         <p><input type="button" id="button" value="Creat an Account"></p>

         <p id="message">
    </p>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-2">
        <div id="gplan" class="ui-widget-content, draggable">
           <p>Great Plan!</p>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div id="pplan" class="ui-widget-content, draggable">
           <p>Poor Plan!</p>
        </div>

       <div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
           <p>Drop Your Plan Here</p>
       </div>

    </div>

    <div id="tabs-3">
        <div id="effect" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
     <p><input type="button" id="feelings" value="Show My Feelings"></p>

     <h2><textarea id="howdoyoufeel" name="feelings" rows="4" cols="30">How Do You Feel Now?
     </textarea></h2>
        </div>


    </div>



</div>
```

Comment: Hi i guess for the edit to your codes, did you already tried to fix some syntax that doesnt have terminators(";")?

Comment: `#gplan` and `#pplan` are `div`s and don't have `value` property.

Comment: @Alex: Another Thing is when I drag a box from tab 2 and drop it in the droppable area, the text in the tab-3 text area changes according to which draggable item I drop in the droppable section. So if I drag and drop gPlan in tab 2 then in tab 3...upon clicking the button the textarea message will change to "Great" or If I drag and drop pPlan in tab two then it correlates to tab 3 and changes the text in tab 3 to "bad" upon clicking the button provided in Tab 3. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: @Muhammad, can you see my questions asked to Alex below? Thank you for help!

Comment: @Muhammad, I revised my code.

Comment: @Muhammad, I tried your code snippet and it still did not store the value of the draggable boxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the behavior you want is to show the text when the user clicks the button, you should change the id in your click listener to be `'#button'`. In your code you're listening for a click event in the textarea.

```
$("#button").click(function(){
```

should fix the issue you're having.

edit: here's a fiddle illustrating this: https://jsfiddle.net/pn06coky/

Comment: this worked well. Another Thing is when I drag a box from tab 2 and drop it in the droppable area, the text in the tab-3 text area changes according to which draggable item I drop in the droppable section. So if I drag and drop gPlan in tab 2 then in tab 3...upon clicking the button the textarea message will change to "Great" or If I drag and drop pPlan in tab two then it correlates to tab 3 and changes the text in tab 3 to "bad" upon clicking the button provided in Tab 3. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: So, when the button is clicked, you want the text in the textarea to change depending on the values of `pPlan` and `gPlan`? If I'm understanding correctly, that's the same behavior as displaying text when both values are undefined. Just add more conditionals to your button on click function that checks for the values of `pPlan` and `gPlan` and change the text area value accordingly. i.e `if(pPlan) { ... }`

Comment: I actually have this coding but i "want the text in the textarea to change depending on the values of pPlan and gPlan" which are selected on the previous tab. So I have 3 tabs. On tab two I have 2 boxes, which are draggable and another div that is a droppable. For example, if within tab # 2 I click and drag pPlan (great plan) into the droppable area, I can then shift over to tab #3 and click the "how do you feel" button and it would display as "great". Sam if on tab #2 I drag and drop pPlan (poor plan) it would display as "poor". I need the values from the drag and drop to be saved.

Comment: if that is the case why dont you save the selected value (the drag & dropped PLAN ) in a variable an then use it on click of the button. or am i not getting it right ?

Comment: @Muhammad, yes that is the concept I am going for. How do I store a "draggable" value in a var?

Comment: could you store $('#droppable').text() in a var?

Answer (score 0):

See below example you can get the draggable and droppable titles in a very simple way, you can use the values to store inside a hidden field according to your needs. Hope that helps you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".idows-file").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $(".idows-folder").droppable({
    accept: ".idows-file",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      let draggableItem = $(ui.draggable[0]);
      let droppableName = $(this)[0].title;
      let draggableName = $(draggableItem).attr('title');
      console.log(droppableName, draggableName);

    }
  });
})
```

```css
.idows-file {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  font-size: 64px;
}

.idows-folder {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  font-size: 64px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="idows-file" title="My-File-name">
  <i class="fa fa-file"></i>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="idows-folder" title="My-Folder-name">
  <i class="fa fa-folder"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Muhammad, unfortunately this did not help me. How do I store the value of a draggable object in tab two to correlate and change the html in tab 3?? depending on which div i drag and drop into the droppable area in tab 2. So what I do in tab 2 should change the text in my textarea in tab 3 upon clicking the button. Any ideas/